# Unable to remove sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html

Login.vue is where I set the sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.response.accessToken)
```

Logout.vue is where I want to delete the sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
```

However, after logout and redirect to Login.vue, the accessToken value is still in the sessionStorage. Am I doing it wrongly ?

Comment: _"the accessToken value is still in the sessionStorage"_ <- how are you verifying this?

Comment: How are you retrieving the access token in `Login.vue`? Is it possible that it's being read prior to the `removeItem()` call?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the token by use it as follow: `sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', null)`?

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` data are only accessible from the page/tab it was created. Trying to manipulate it from another page/tab/window will not work.

Consider using `localStorage` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Use LocalStorage,

To Add Item

```
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.response.accessToken);
```

To Remove Item,

```
localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
```

Comment: _"Use LocalStorage"_ why?

Comment: Session storage gave me problems like that, then i had to use **sessionStorage.clear();** , to clear all session values. Then i moved to localStorage. It never gave me problems like that.

Comment: `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are identical except the latter is automatically cleared when the page session ends. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I just observed similar behaviour in Chrome. `localStorage` worked as intended. `sessionStorage` failed to remove the item. `getItem` immediately after `removeItem` returned the old data. Exactly the same code with `localStorage` was not a problem.